# how to get fully dark kibana?

Tags: themes, visualization, kibana

I'm starting with kibana and I see a lot of pictures where kibana has different visual than on official web site.
I like it more but I can't find how to switch on it.
You may think that I'm talking bout black dashboard theme but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.
On pictures I saw kibana seems to be fully dark and even have different layout.

Let me show

[image: the tool bar]

[image: dark introduction page]

[image: Query and filtering buttons]

Hope now it's understandable what I mean.

If so, can someone help me and tell how can I get this fully dark kibana ?
or tell me where I'm wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it as on your pictures then just use Kibana 3.

Answer (score 12):

Under `Management > Advanced Setting > "dashboard:defaultDarkTheme"` you can set this field to True, which will affect the dashboard to be dark themed. Anyhow, the dark theme only works in the dashboard right now.

Answer (score 3):

You are using Kibana 3, current version is 4 default dashboards is a white. Change setting in dashboards for dark if you need.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/dashboard.html#creating-a-new-dashboard

Answer (score 1):

Kibana 4.2 now has a dark theme: https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-4-2-0