# Need Color Tile Map in Dark Theme Dashboard kibana

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

After changing the dashboard theme from white to dark, map color is in black and white format. But I want the map in color format. Please help me.

Normal Kibana Dashboard:

[image: Normal Kibana Dashboard]

Dark Theme Kibana Dashboard

[image: Dark Theme Kibana Dashboard]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get fully dark kibana?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34368556/how-to-get-fully-dark-kibana)

Comment: It is not duplicate. I am looking for color map in dark theme.

Comment: Hey Guys, Please read the question carefully before giving the thumps down.

Comment: I believe that can't be done right now.

Comment: Yes, It can not be done right now. We can get color format in dark theme with less detailed map( https://github.com/snuids/jVectorMapKibana )